# Android Bluetooth Serial Communication reads symbol "�"

Tags: android, bluetooth

I've written Android code to connect to bluetooth HC-05, to send commands to HC-05 and receive different data related to commands sent.
The Android app connects bluetooth and on sending 1st command it receives exact data what I want but on next command it receives symbol "�" along with relevant data.

I've tested hardware circuit with other bluetooth terminals on Android and it works perfect.

Following is my code for serial communication:

```
void beginListenForData() {
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        final byte delimiter = 10; 
        stopWorker = false;
        readBufferPosition = 0;
        readBuffer = new byte[1024];
        workerThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() && !stopWorker) {
                    try {
                        int bytesAvailable = mmInputStream.available();

                        if (bytesAvailable > 0) {
                            byte[] packetBytes = new byte[bytesAvailable];
                            mmInputStream.read(packetBytes);

                            for (int i = 0; i < bytesAvailable; i++) {
                                byte b = packetBytes[i];
                                if (b == delimiter) {
                                    byte[] encodedBytes = new        byte[readBufferPosition];
                                    System.arraycopy(readBuffer, 0,
                                            encodedBytes, 0,
                                            encodedBytes.length);
                                    final String data = new String(
                                            encodedBytes,"US-ASCII" );
                                    readBufferPosition = 0;

                                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                        public void run() {
                                            sampleView.setText(data);
                                            str = sampleView.getText()
                                                    .toString();
                                            Log.i("Data", data);                                        
 }

                                    });
                                } else {
                                    readBuffer[readBufferPosition++] = b;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        stopWorker = true;
                    }
                }

            }


        });

        workerThread.start();
        try {


            String command1=command.getText().toString();
            mmOutputStream.write(command1.getBytes());



        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

Sometime,this kind of messy code occurs,you should pay attention to your charset format.You can convert your command both to "UTF-8".

Another situation may be:you read the data from the wrong start or end position.

Comment: Sorry for late reply... I had tried "UTF-8" but there was no change in situation.

Comment: What is the HEX representation of this symbol? It is not necessarily “�” but may be representation of "unrecognised" character.
I guess the problem is your delimiter detection. if there is a UTF character sent by HC-05 which has 0x10 as lower byte it may be misinterpreted by your code.

Comment: If the problem is delimiter detection then it would always send this symbols. But in case of first command it sends correct data and second command on wards it code reads symbols along with data. What changes do you think I should make in above code?